# Open a new browser window throgh server side in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i want to open a browser window and define the window size.
I was trying to do this but its not working.

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('" + "Messeage.aspx" + "' , width=300px ,height=300px);</script>");
```

Comment: Maybe the browser's popup blocker is blocking it.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with: Response.Write("<script>window.open('Messeage.aspx', width=300px ,height=300px);</script>");

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
 Response.Write("<script>window.open('" + "Messeage.aspx" + "' , 'width=300' ,'height=300');</script>");
```